# search result page not working magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Hi when I search for my Magento 2 site if product didn't exist its working fine and showing this message

> Your search returned no results.

but when the product exists in the system its showing page like this[image]

can anyone please tell me what the issue with this I have already checked exception and log files nothing is there

Comment: Seems to you have issue related to pagination, Have you customize pagination.

Comment: actually i am using theme versatile

Comment: did you check by disabling template and layout file of magento_search of you theme

Comment: yeah found it issue was with theme thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution my theme was creating this issue in this file

> app/design/frontend/Meigee/versatile/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/filter.phtml

hope it may helpful for others as well.